# Google pay pass location notification is not working

Tags: android, google-pay

I am trying to `push notification from Google Pay Wallet Pass`.

When the user comes to a defined location, it's not working.

We have already **enabled location services** and we **gave permissions for Google Pay**, Still we are unable to get the location based notifications.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please see the notification use cases documentation, there are limits. https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/offers/use-cases#geofenced-notifications